# Concentration inequality for sum of iid squares of sub-Exponential variables

Tags: probability, statistics

If $X_i$ follows sub-Exponetial distribution, can we obtain the following inequality:
$$
P(X_1^2+\cdots+X_n^2>nt)\le nP(X_1^2>nt)
$$
I just saw this answer from this page: [Concentration inequality for sum of squares of i.i.d. sub-exponential random variables?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1652781/concentration-inequality-for-sum-of-squares-of-i-i-d-sub-exponential-random-var#)

However I still cannot figure out why it holds. Could someone give me some explanations or references? Thanks a lot!